# How to display content from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have a problem about my homework. I'm trying to make a 3-ball game. I created the balls, the cases for collision but when i try to display point when collision happened, it doesn't show.

This is my ball class

```
int point = 0;
public int setpoint() { 
    point = point+1;
        System.out.println(point);
    return point;
}

double sz=40;
double Vx=2,Vy=2;
double Vx2=0,Vy2=0,Vx3=0,Vy3=0,Vx4=0,Vy4=0;
double V=10;
Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200,sz,sz);
Ellipse2D.Double ball2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(150,100,sz,sz);
Ellipse2D.Double ball3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(400,100,sz,sz);
Ellipse2D.Double ball4 = new Ellipse2D.Double(240,100,sz,sz);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,3,200);
Timer t = new Timer(15,this);

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    updateBallPosition();


}


public void updateBallPosition() {


    ball.x+=Vx;
    ball.y+=Vy;

    ball2.x+=Vx2;
    ball2.y+=Vy2;

    ball3.x+=Vx3;
    ball3.y+=Vy3;


    ball4.x+=Vx4;
    ball4.y+=Vy4;


    Vx = Vx*0.99;
    Vy = Vy*0.99;

    Vx2 = Vx2*0.99;
    Vy2 = Vy2*0.99;

    Vx3 = Vx3*0.99;
    Vy3 = Vy3*0.99;

    Vx4 = Vx4*0.99;
    Vy4 = Vy4*0.99;




    if(ball.x<0 || ball.x>getWidth()-sz) 
        Vx=-Vx;

    if(ball.y<0 || ball.y>getHeight()-sz) Vy=-Vy;

    if(ball2.x<0 || ball2.x>getWidth()-sz) Vx2=-Vx2;
    if(ball2.y<0 || ball2.y>getHeight()-sz) Vy2=-Vy2 ;

    if(ball3.x<0 || ball3.x>getWidth()-sz) Vx3=-Vx3;
    if(ball3.y<0 || ball3.y>getHeight()-sz) Vy3=-Vy3;

    if(ball4.x<0 || ball4.x>getWidth()-sz) Vx4=-Vx4;
    if(ball4.y<0 || ball4.y>getHeight()-sz) Vy4=-Vy4;


    double dx = ball2.x - ball.x;
    double dy = ball2.y - ball.y;

    double dx1 = ball3.x - ball.x;
    double dy1 = ball3.y - ball.y;

    double dx2 = ball4.x - ball.x;
    double dy2 = ball4.y - ball.y;

    double dx4 = ball3.x - ball4.x;
    double dy4 = ball3.y - ball4.y;

    double dx5 = ball4.x - ball2.x;
    double dy5 = ball4.y - ball2.y;

    double dx6 = ball3.x - ball2.x;
    double dy6 = ball3.y - ball2.y;



    double Umag = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
    double Umag2 = Math.hypot(dx1, dy1);
    double Umag3 = Math.hypot(dx2, dy2);

    double Umag4 = Math.hypot(dx4, dy4);
    double Umag5 = Math.hypot(dx5, dy5);
    double Umag6 = Math.hypot(dx6, dy6);


    if(Umag <= ball.width)
    {


        double VrMag = (Vx*dx + Vy*dy )/ Umag;
        double Vrx = VrMag * dx / Umag;
        double Vry = VrMag * dy / Umag;

        double Vtx = Vx - Vrx;
        double Vty = Vy - Vry;


        Vx = Vtx;
        Vy = Vty;
        Vx2 = Vrx;
        Vy2 = Vry;
        setpoint();
        a++;
    }
    else if(Umag2 <= ball.width)
    {


        double VrMag1 = (Vx*dx1 + Vy*dy1 )/ Umag2;
        double Vrx1 = VrMag1 * dx1 / Umag2;
        double Vry1 = VrMag1 * dy1 / Umag2;

        double Vtx1 = Vx - Vrx1;
        double Vty1 = Vy - Vry1;


        Vx = Vtx1;
        Vy = Vty1;
        Vx3 = Vrx1;
        Vy3 = Vry1;
        setpoint();
        a++;

    }
    else if(Umag3 <= ball.width)
    {


        double VrMag2 = (Vx*dx2 + Vy*dy2 )/ Umag3;
        double Vrx2 = VrMag2 * dx2 / Umag3;
        double Vry2 = VrMag2 * dy2 / Umag3;

        double Vtx2 = Vx - Vrx2;
        double Vty2 = Vy- Vry2;


        Vx = Vtx2;
        Vy = Vty2;
        Vx4 = Vrx2;
        Vy4 = Vry2;
        setpoint();
        a++;
    }

    else if(Umag4 <= ball4.width)
    {


        double VrMag4 = (Vx4*dx4 + Vy4*dy4 )/ Umag4;
        double Vrx4 = VrMag4 * dx4 / Umag4;
        double Vry4 = VrMag4 * dy4/ Umag4;

        double Vtx4 = Vx4 - Vrx4;
        double Vty4 = Vy4 - Vry4;


        Vx4 = Vtx4;
        Vy4 = Vty4;
        Vx3 = Vrx4;
        Vy3 = Vry4;
        setpoint();

    }
    else if(Umag5 <= ball2.width)
    {


        double VrMag5 = (Vx2*dx5 + Vy2*dy5 )/ Umag5;
        double Vrx5 = VrMag5 * dx5 / Umag5;
        double Vry5 = VrMag5 * dy5 / Umag5;

        double Vtx5 = Vx2 - Vrx5;
        double Vty5 = Vy2 - Vry5;


        Vx2 = Vtx5;
        Vy2 = Vty5;
        Vx4 = Vrx5;
        Vy4 = Vry5;
        setpoint();
    }
    else if (Umag6 <= ball2.width)
    {


        double VrMag6 = (Vx2*dx6 + Vy2*dy6 )/ Umag6;
        double Vrx6 = VrMag6 * dx6 / Umag6;
        double Vry6 = VrMag6 * dy6 / Umag6;

        double Vtx6 = Vx2 - Vrx6;
        double Vty6 = Vy2 - Vry6;


        Vx2 = Vtx6;
        Vy2 = Vty6;
        Vx3 = Vrx6;
        Vy3 = Vry6;
        setpoint();

    }
```

```
And this is my main function:
```

```
    BallPanel op = new BallPanel();



    JLabel ds = new JLabel("Game is starting! ");
    JLabel asd = new JLabel(" ");


    Timer s = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {

        int time = 0;   
        int y = op.setpoint();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        time++;


        ds.setText(format(time));
        asd.setText(format(y));
    }

    });
    s.start();



    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ball");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel statusbar = new JPanel();
    frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JLabel as = new JLabel("Time: ");
    JLabel das = new JLabel("seconds");
    statusbar.add(as);
    statusbar.add(ds);
    statusbar.add(das);
    statusbar.add(asd);


    BallPanel bp = new BallPanel();





    bp.addKeyListener(bp);
    bp.addMouseListener(bp);
    frame.add(bp);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.addKeyListener(bp);


    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}


 public static String format(int i) {
        String result = String.valueOf(i);
        if (result.length() == 1) {
            result = "0" + result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It should increase point and shows it in statusbar but it just starts with 01 then nothing happens. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: So, conceptually, a "ball" should represent the state of a single ball.  "collision" detection should be handled by the "controller". This allows you to seperate the responsibilities and allow each class to focus on the individual needs/requirements that they should be responsible for.  This also allows you to better manage the information flow through the app and will make it easier for your to gain access to the information that you need

Comment: Oh, and, `int y = op.setpoint();` will need to be updated on every iteration of your `Timer`, not just when it's instantiated

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for your response but i can't understand the suggestion about controller. Also, when i try to put int y = op.setpoint(); to actionPerformed class (this is what i understood from your second comment) it becomes as same as time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It's quite difficult to assess the problems in your code as it stands because it is quite poorly structured. You have not encapsulated the details of a ball so that the logic is in a single place. Rather you have repeated the same logic several times. This makes your code error prone and hard to read.

I suggest you start by creating a ball class that represents a single ball. Here's a framework for you. I recommend you write unit tests for each of the methods and make sure they work effectively before writing your 'main' loop. If you could repost with this structure I suspect you'll find the help more effective:

```
class Ball {
    private Ellipse2D.Double shape;
    private double xVelocity;
    private double yVelocity;

    public void update(double period) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean overlaps(Ball other) {
        ...
    }
}
```